# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column product_code in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I have this line in mysql procedure

```
UPDATE mytable SET product_code =  p_code  WHERE  mytable.product_id=p_id ;
```

it produces this error:

> `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column product_code in 'field list'`

I don't understand what is the problem? Why is it giving this error ?

**update**:
the table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `forein_key` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `some_other_field` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `other_field` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`,`another_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3553 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATE_PRODUCT_ID $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PRODUCT_ID()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE p_code varchar(20);
DECLARE p_id int(11);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT product_id, product_code FROM product;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product INTO n;
SET i=0;
OPEN cur1;
WHILE i<n DO
    FETCH cur1 INTO p_id, p_code;
    UPDATE mytable SET mytable.product_code =  p_code  WHERE  mytable.product_id=p_id ;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
End $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL UPDATE_PRODUCT_ID();
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your table?

Comment: It means your table 'mytable' doesn't have a column namend 'product_code'. Verify the table structure!

Comment: The only problem I can see is field `p_id` which doesn't exist in your table.The actual query that produces the error should be different.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes p_id is a variable in the procedure just like the p_code

Comment: Can you show us then the exact query that produces the error?

Comment: sure, I have added the procedure

Comment: Could the 'product' table not have the column?

Comment: @pintxo yes you are right I noticed that now (Y)